# ssh tunnel - bind: Address already in use

Tags: server, ssh, tunnel

I am running on my VPS `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` and locally `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` and I want to create a ssh-tunnel to connect to my database to run `SELECT`'s for reporting in my `laravel 6` application.

My production database has the following credentials on my server:

```
DB_HOST_PROD=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_PROD=3306
DB_DATABASE_PROD=test_db
DB_USERNAME_PROD=root
DB_PASSWORD_PROD=prod_pwd
```

When running my `ssh-command` I get:

```
admin@admin-VirtualBox:~$ /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -v -N -i /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa -L 13307:127.0.0.1:3306 -p 22 root@xx.xx.xxx.xx
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xx [xx.xx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xx.xx.xxx.xx:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xxx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xx.xx.xxx.xx ([xx.xx.xxx.xx]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:13307 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:3306
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 13307.
bind: Address already in use
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 13307.
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 13307
Could not request local forwarding.
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
```

I am running locally my development database on:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=local_pwd
```

Why do I get the message `bind: Address already in use`?

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is self-explanatory. Some program is already using port 13307.
Try running `netstat -antp` as root, look for the port 13307 and you should see the PID of the related program. It's possible that you already have a stale SSH connection. Plus, you might need the -R option for reverse SSH.

Possibly useful post: [Knowing if a remote port forward was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514113/6843158)

Comment: Thx! How can I kill the program that uses this port?

Comment: `kill 1234`, where 1234 is the PID...